# Error while launching eclipse from other user login

Tags: eclipse

I had installed eclipse in /usr/local/eclipse.So that other users of my mac can access the same. However, When I try to launch from other users login, following error is coming:

```
Locking is not possible in the directory "/usr/local/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi". A common reason is that the file system or Runtime Environment does not support file locking for that location. Please choose a different location, or disable file locking passing "-Dosgi.locking=none" as a VM argument.
/usr/local/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager/.fileTableLock (Permission denied
```

To solve this problem, I have added following line in ~/.bash_profile

```
alias eclipse='eclipse -configuration ~/eclipse'
```

Reference:http://computer-help-tips.blogspot.in/2011/05/users-encountering-invalid.html

When I try to launch eclipse from command line, it works fine but when I launch it from Dock same alert is coming up.
What is the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the lock file-s permissions are set correctly for all users you intend to use eclipse. If I'm not mistaken, there are lock files in several of the plugins. Perhaps worth using find to identify them:

```
 find . -name .fileTableLock -exec ls -las {} \;
```

There is also a mention of using "-Dosgi.locking=none" indicating you can turn off the need for locking but that didn't work for me. I ultimately changed the permissions...

**Update following edit:**

Once locating each file you would use `chmod` to change the rights for users in the appropriate group - i.e. put these eclipse lock files in an "eclipse" group (man or google `groupadd` and `chgrp`) with group permissisons `rw` and add your users to that "eclipse" group too (man `groups`,  `usermod -G`). For example:

```
$ groupadd eclipse                # Create new "eclipse" group
$ chgrp eclipse .fileTableLock    # Put .fileTableLock in group eclipse
$ usermodd -a -G eclipse userx    # Add userx to eclipse group
$ chmod g+rw .fileTableLock       # Ensure .fileTableLock read-write for eclipse group
```

Comment: There are so many files. So what I have to change in these lock files. Please check my edited question.